# Complex mapping from SQL Reader to Object

Tags: c#

I need to map the result of a stored procedure to a complex object:

Lets say my stored procedure returns columns A,B,C,D,E,F

I have a class, say:

```
class ABC{
    public int A;
    public string B;
    public int C;

    public virtual ICollection<DEF> DEFObj;
}
```

and class DEF is as:

```
class DEF{
     int value;
     string comment;
}
```

So, here, I need to take column D,E,F values and store them in the `ICollection<DEF>` object as a list.

Which would be the best way to get this done, would Automapper be a good place to start or is there something else?

PS: My data is in an SQL Reader object.

Comment: An ORM (object relational mapper, such as NHibernate) would work best, if you have the time to implement it and if your application allows it.  Automapper is better for mapping typed models from one to another, but it could probably be used in this scenario.  You could also just write your own mapping function...

Comment: If you give an example of a result set, and the expected resultant objects, it would be easier to provide suggestions for how to map from one to the other in C#.

Comment: Do you need to process the data a little before mapping? Are there multiple DEF values for the same set of ABC?

Comment: @MaxwellTroyMiltonKing: Yes there are

Comment: Would column D, E and F each have their own instance of class DEF? If not, what column maps to what member?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your responses to the comments, it sounds like there is a one-to-many relationship between a unique tuple `(A, B, C)` and possibly many potentially non-unique values `(D, E, F)`. This lends itself to the interface `IDictionary<ABC, ICollection<DEF>>`.

As you are using a `SqlDataReader`, you'll have to pay the price of iterating through it anyway, so you might as well get your objects in one go.

```
IDictionary<ABC, ICollection<DEF>> data = new Dictionary<ABC, ICollection<DEF>>();
int _a = reader.GetOrdinal("a"), _b = reader.GetOrdinal("b"), _c = reader.GetOrdinal("c");
int _value = reader.GetOrdinal("value"), _comment = reader.GetOrdinal("comment");
while (reader.Read()) {
    ABC key = new ABC { A = reader.GetInt32(_a), B = reader.GetString(_b), C = reader.GetInt32(_c) };
    ICollection<DEF> values;
    if (!data.TryGetValue(key, out values)) {
        data[key] = (values = new List<DEF>());
    }
    values.Add(new DEF { value = reader.GetInt32(_value), comment = reader.GetString(_comment) });
}
```

Now you can keep your relationship separate from your model, but if you wanted to denormalize them into a view model, for example, you could use:

```
class ABCDEF {
    public int A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public int C { get; set; }
    public ICollection<DEF> DEF { get; set; }
}
```

And populate however you prefer. Example using LINQ:

```
data.Select(d => new ABCDEF {
    A = d.Key.A,
    B = d.Key.B,
    C = d.Key.C,
    DEF = d.Value.ToArray()
});
```

If you do need to use the structure of the classes above, tailor to suit.

Answer (score 0):

You could use linq to create the objects in a pretty clean way.

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = CallStoredProcedure())
{
   return reader.Cast<System.Data.Common.DbDataRecord>().Select(rec => new ABC()
   {
      A = (int)rec[0],
      B = rec.GetString(1),
      C = (int)rec[2],
      DEFObj = // iterate over rec[3]? Don't know what your data looks like at this point...
   }).toList();
}
```